# Calling spring authorization server OAuth2 REST endpoints

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

Trying to implement the OAuth2 protocol using [Spring Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server). Created a simple application with the following configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class AuthorizationServerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<AuthorizationServerApplication>(*args)
}
```

```
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration::class)
class AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    fun registeredClientRepository(): RegisteredClientRepository? {
        val registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("client")
            .clientSecret("{noop}client-secret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
            .redirectUri("http://example-host:9002/test/admin")
            .redirectUri("http://example-host:9002/test")
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .scope("read")
            .build()
        return InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient)
    }

    ...

    @Bean
    fun providerSettings(): ProviderSettings? {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
            .issuer("http://example-host:9000")
            .build()
    }
}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun defaultSecurityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
        http
            .authorizeRequests { authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            }
            // these are disabled so that I won't get any additional issue this needs to be changed
            .formLogin().disable()
            .csrf().disable()

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun users(): UserDetailsService? {
        val admin: UserDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .authorities("read", "write")
            .build()

        val user: UserDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .authorities("read")
            .build()
        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user)
    }
}
```

When calling the following endpoint: `GET http://example-host:9000/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server` I get back these:

```
{
    "issuer": "http://example-host:9000",
    "authorization_endpoint": "http://example-host:9000/oauth2/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "http://example-host:9000/oauth2/token",
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_jwt",
        "private_key_jwt"
    ],
    "jwks_uri": "http://example-host:9000/oauth2/jwks",
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code"
    ],
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "client_credentials",
        "refresh_token"
    ],
    "revocation_endpoint": "http://example-host:9000/oauth2/revoke",
    "revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_jwt",
        "private_key_jwt"
    ],
    "introspection_endpoint": "http://example-host:9000/oauth2/introspect",
    "introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_jwt",
        "private_key_jwt"
    ],
    "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
        "S256"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to go past authentication and trying to follow [this documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-3.2). I tried multiple calls one of these is:

```
curl --location --request POST 'example-host:9000/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=client-secret'
```

I get back 401 most of the time with different messages. Can't really figure out where I can find some documentation with examples as the examples that I was able to find are not really helpful for my usecase. I don't fully get how I would be able to authenticate and use the resource servers' endpoints in case of the client being a front-end application. Maybe I misunderstood something?

**Edit:**
Adding trace logs from authorization server when requesting token endpoint:

```
curl --location --request POST 'example-host:9000/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=client-secret' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password'
```

```
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$746/0x000000080105b608@7a764446, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@841f2ce, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@38eb32b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4232bd1e, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.ProviderContextFilter@1c463b0b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6e87e57e, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3657ca3e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@36c9161d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@c85053, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@827dabb, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@3fce33c2, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@5f5e39a5, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@6f53bec6, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1be28be5, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@12322dee, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4aba4a37, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3c29c1e5, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5e60456e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5771f1b4, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@1ec08e27, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@548d0a8d, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@6c15398a, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcUserInfoEndpointFilter@6bcb4915]] (1/2)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 DEBUG 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth2/token
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 DEBUG 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ProviderContextFilter (4/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (5/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (6/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$746/0x000000080105b608@7a764446]]]
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (7/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (8/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter (9/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.154 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter (10/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.155 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (11/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.155 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter (12/22)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.155 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with JwtClientAssertionAuthenticationProvider (1/11)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.155 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider (2/11)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.155 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with PublicClientAuthenticationProvider (3/11)
2022-06-14 16:41:47.155 TRACE 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2022-06-14 16:41:47.155 DEBUG 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-06-14 16:41:47.156 DEBUG 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-06-14 16:41:47.156 DEBUG 34744 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: I think you get confused with the users and the client. You should use the client's user & password (i.e., 'client:client-secret') when calling the server, instead of the user's credentials.

Comment: [yoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504807/yoni) I tried that as well I get the same response. `{ "error": "invalid_client" }`

Comment: See [Default Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-model.html#default-configuration) in the docs, which mentions `"The authorization_code grant requires the resource owner to be authenticated. Therefore, a user authentication mechanism must be configured in addition to the default OAuth2 security configuration."`. I would start with the [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#developing-your-first-application) example.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're looking to build a public client, which cannot authenticate with the server, so you'll need to enable PKCE. You may be interested in [this example](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/b7ad8f2468830d24cf34266974b5b48b5a3bd2a7/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L82-L92) for configuring support for a public client and [this webinar](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/webinars/mar-10-getting-started-with-spring-authorization-server) for more info on that example.

Comment: Thank you [Steve Riesenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15835039/steve-riesenberg)! You are right I was looking for something like a public client and just wanted to make sure I understood how this implementation worked first that's why I started with this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your case you don't need the `Authorization` header in your request for token since you explicitly allowed all requests to pass through via `authorizeRequests.anyRequest().permitAll()`.

Second, in your `curl` request you didn't specify at least a desired grant type and its parameters.

For example, for the `password` grant type the request might look something like this:

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'example-host:9000/oauth2/token' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=client-secret' \ 
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \ 
--data-urlencode 'username=user' \ 
--data-urlencode 'password=password'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

1. Spring authorization server 0.3.0 doesn't support the `password` grant type, exactly as it shows in the `grant_types_supported` section of the `.well-known/oauth-authorization-server` endpoint output. There's just no such authentication provider in the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication` package.
2. To make at least the `client_credentials` token request work, add

```java
.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
```

and (in case you'd like to pass the `client_id` and `client_secret` inside the POST body)

```java
.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
```

to your `RegisteredClient` in the `registeredClientRepository`.
Then this can be tested with

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'http://example-host:9000/oauth2/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=client&client_secret=client-secret'
```

(be sure to pass the actual `client_id` and `client_secret` of a `RegisteredClient`)

Also, if you import `OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration` a default `SecurityFilterChain` for the auth server endpoints is  created and there's no need to define it manually. On the other hand a `SecurityFilterChain` for your app authentication is likely still needed.

3. To debug the OAuth authentication process and see the exact exceptions, if any, set some breakpoints in the `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#authenticate()` method

Comment: Thank you [dekkard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571544/dekkard) I tried that as well exactly the same response `invalid_client` will add trace logs to my question as well.

Comment: Please set `debug=true` to your application properties and add the full log of your request being processed. The one you added shows no indication of an error.

Comment: [dekkard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571544/dekkard) I have these 2 properties set
`logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` in application properties and created [Gist with full application log](https://gist.github.com/GROX13/96f9030a2398fd263185ad508dbef8fb) I don't think there would be anything additional. I started the application and called the token endpoint once.

Comment: Just noticed that the output of `.well-known/oauth-authorization-server` shows no `password` grant type in the `grant_types_supported` section for some reason. Try the `client_credentials` grant type, just to check if your configuration works at all: `curl -L -X POST 'example-host:9000/oauth2/token' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' --data-urlencode 'client_id=client' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=client-secret'`

Comment: I still get `{ "error": "invalid_client" }`. I tried different grant types as well and can't really find anything useful with all my experiments.

Comment: Can you share a minimal project with the configuration in question that can be used to reproduce this issue?

Comment: [dekkard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571544/dekkard) sure will push on GitHub as soon as I'll have chance

Comment: [dekkard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571544/dekkard) adding link with GitHub repo https://github.com/GROX13/spring-authorization-server-demo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245645/discussion-between-grox13-and-dekkard).

Answer (score 0):

your client id and client secret must be on Base64 format.

```
String hashed_keys = Base64.encode("client_id:client_secret");
```

and you must pass it as http header

```
curl -L -X POST 'http://example-host:9000/oauth2/token' -H "Authorisation: hashed_keys" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Comment: did u get any fix for this. i am facing the same issue